# Reindex required after reindexing?

Tags: reindex, index

I'm trying to re-index my Magento store and its stuck on re_index required, even after re-indexing..

The only thing I've done to it recently is add a filter extension by Aitoc.

It's also making the filter not work as intended too.

If anyone can give me some pointers I'd appreciate it,

Thanks

Comment: Did you do the reindex on Backend or shell?

Comment: Via the backend and via SSH but when I refresh the index management page it still shows re-index required

Comment: Arkward. Andy reindex-errors in the shell?

Comment: Oooh god yeah, loads, seems to be constantly updating..

Comment: Mayebe you should not post serverpaths for security reasons ;)

Comment: Try to resolve the version error with updateing all sourcefiles. MAybe it helps. Have a close look at magento-filerights too

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it programmatically. This way:

```
$indexCollection = Mage::getModel('index/process')->getCollection();
    foreach ($indexCollection as $index) {
      $index->reindexAll();
  }
```